# While Ubuntu 14.04 boots up, I get continuous strange strings of square brackets on the screen

Tags: boot

My screen shows continuous some symbols while the system is starting up. If I press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key it will stop, otherwise it goes on and on for around 5-10 minutes.

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

I made [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNtnZVqEpMA&feature=youtu.be) to illustrate the problem.

[image: screenshot from the video]

Comment: You've probably got a stuck key on your keyboard. Unplug the laptop's internal keyboard, and try using an external USB keyboard to confirm this.

Comment: I already use external keyboard, still I'm facing this problem at system boot. No problem faced when system booted.

Comment: Unplug either keyboard, reboot system, observe results. It's likely one keyboard or the other.

Comment: tried this, but still facing the problem

Comment: Unplug BOTH keyboards, and ALL other USB devices, and retry.

Comment: I use laptop, so can't unplug the integrated keyboard. I don't think there is problem of keyboard because, once the system started , everything is normal.  Also earlier I used to use windows, there i didn't face any problem of this kind.

Comment: To my first suggestion to **unplug the laptop's internal keyboard**, you said "tried this, but still facing the problem". Now you say "I use laptop, so can't unplug the integrated keyboard." It's hard to see in your picture, but it looks like it's repeating control characters, and you might not see a problem in Windows/Ubuntu, once it's booted to an OS. The laptop keyboard is not that difficult to unplug. Removing two or three screws will allow you to get to the keyboard cable. Search YouTube for videos on how to do it for your model computer, and give it a try.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue Chandra Prakash. Did you find the solution?

Comment: Found a solution to this?